# Spring boot auto configuration overriding custom (elasticsearchTemplate) configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have created the following configuration (I duplicated the @Lazy because I was not able to make it work)

```
@Lazy(true)
@Configuration
public class ElasticConfiguration
{
   private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticConfiguration.class);

   @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
   private String esHost;

   @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
   private int esPort;

   @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
   private String esClusterName;

   @Lazy(true)
   @Bean
   public Client client() throws Exception
   {
      Builder builder = Settings.builder();
      // builder.put("client.transport.sniff", true);
      Settings settings = builder.put("cluster.name", esClusterName).build();
      TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
      InetAddress adress = InetAddress.getByName(esHost);
      client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(adress, esPort));
      logger.debug(
         "ES Client built with cluster.name;" + esClusterName + ";host;" + esHost + ";port;" + esPort + ";client.transport.sniff;"
            + builder.get("client.transport.sniff"));
      return client;
   }

   @Lazy(true)
   @Bean
   public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception
   {
      return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
   }
}
```

I am not able to have the lazy initialization because it seems my configuration is overriden by spring-boot auto configuration

> Overriding bean definition for bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' with a
>   different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=true; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=elasticConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [xxx/xxx/ElasticConfiguration.class]]
>   with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false;
>   autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true;
>   primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=elasticsearchTemplate; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class]]

I also tried to add the following annotation on the class

```
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

in association with the following property, but it did not work better

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=xxx.xxx.ElasticConfiguration
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the only solution I found was to use the following property

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration
```

Note that using the folling annotation did not work for me ...

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

**EDIT**

In fact my problem was that my method `elasticsearchTemplate()` was returning `ElasticsearchOperations` instead of `ElasticsearchTemplate`.

When changing the signature the @Lazy annotation seems to work.